# Transcode CMYK TIFF files with Batik (Java)

Tags: java, svg, tiff, batik, cmyk

I am trying to convert an `SVG` file via Batik to `TIFF`.
In the SVG File all the color values are defined as `device-cmyk`. The SVG looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M30,1h40l29,29v40l-29,29h-40l-29-29v-40z" stroke="#CD853F device-cmyk(0.11, 0.48, 0.83, 0.00)" fill="#CD853F device-cmyk(0.11, 0.48, 0.83, 0.00)"/>
</svg>
```

I am using `TIFFTranscoder` to create the files:

```
byte[] bytes = svgFileAsString.getBytes("UTF-8");
ByteArrayInputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
TranscoderInput transcoderInput = new TranscoderInput(byteInputStream);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
TranscoderOutput transcodeOutput = new TranscoderOutput(byteOutputStream);
TIFFTranscoder tiffConverter = new TIFFTranscoder();
tiffConverter.transcode(transcoderInput, transcodeOutput);
byteOutputStream.flush();
byteOutputStream.close();
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("svgtiff.tiff"), byteOutputStream.toByteArray());
```

After creation the `TIFF` file only contains the RGB values. Does anyone knows how to define what color-model the `TIFF` should use?